# Vector Clock different implementations

Tags: vector-clock

It is very well-known that Vector clocks detect causal dependencies between events, but there are different implementation methods.
What are the differences (advantages/disadvantages) between:

- ticking only when sending (before).
- ticking only when sending (after).
- ticking when receiving and ticking before sending
- ticking when receiving and ticking after sending

Answer (score 0):

It is suppose to tick right before sending and also tick right before receiving. The word right before here means the event represented send/receive will have the vector clock timestamp of right after the vector clock has just been updated with a tick.

The reason is because there are 2 processes, the sender process and the receiver process.

It needs to tick the sending event so that the sender process is aware that a send event has just occurred. Correspondingly, it also needs to tick in the receiving event so that the receiver process is aware that a receive event has just occurred.

Otherwise, it would violate Lamport's happened before relation in either sender or receiver if a tick did not occur there.